# Why does PDO allow to use indexed array with named placeholders, but only when emulation is disabled?

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

Recently I learned that PDO allows to use *indexed* array with named placeholders, like this:

```
$stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO TABLE (one, two) VALUES (:one, :two)");
$stmt->execute([1,2]);
```

surprisingly, it works, as well as more familiar

```
$stmt->execute(["one" => 1, "two" => 2]);
```

I would have expected this code to throw an error, which it does, but only when PDO emulation mode is turned off - i.e. when native prepared statements are used:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("select :one one, :two two");
$stmt->execute([1,2]);
var_dump($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("select :one one, :two two");
$stmt->execute([1,2]);
var_dump($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

[which outputs a regular array for the first code snippet and an error for the second](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php81/f71f977849754865bf2709158f9b3057/):

> Fatal error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in  at line: 9

It seems this behavior is common for most database drivers except for Oracle (that errors out on both code snippets) and Sqlite3 (that allows both).

Not that I find this approach a good idea but would like to understand how it's possible.

Comment: According to the manual [ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) only has an effect on Oracle, Firebird and MySQL databases. That would explain why Sqlite3 is agnostic about this setting.

Comment: Here https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c#L1606  there is an connections between PDO_ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES and stmt->supports_placeholders == PDO_PLACEHOLDER_NONE, im not so much into C. But maybe this is related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I get to the explanation let's state some facts:

- MySQL does not support named placeholders
- PDO supports named and positional placeholders regardless of the database driver and emulation mode
- In non-emulated mode `prepare()` sends the SQL string to MySQL for preparation of the native PS; in emulated mode the SQL is send only on `execute()` with placeholders substituted for values

#### Explanation

When you call `prepare()` in non-emulated mode with PDO_MySQL driver, PDO must parse the SQL and send it off to MySQL. Because MySQL only supports positional placeholders, PDO replaces all named placeholders with `?`. For example, if you prepare a query `SELECT :name AS foo`, PDO is forced to send `SELECT ? AS foo`.

When you call `execute()`, PDO needs to bind params to placeholders. The issue at this point is that the SQL query no longer has named placeholders. But PDO remembers the named placeholders as they appeared in the SQL mapped to their ordinal numbers. Because the parameter binding in MySQL happens using positional parameters, the named params need to be remapped to their ordinal numbers, but positional params don't. They only need to be checked against the placeholder map to make sure that the array index corresponds to a valid placeholder<sup>*</sup>.

You can see the code here [https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c#L44](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/0ec8733bf40a9f276cde8fd8b26c7f2a74270e71/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c#L44)

Emulated prepares work a little differently. There's no parameter binding so this whole logic does not apply. When an emulated PS is executed, the parser simply replaces each named placeholder with quoted (see `PDO::quote()`) string literal taken from the param array. That's why the named placeholder can appear in SQL multiple times because the position is irrelevant.

It's also worth pointing out that some database drivers support named parameters and/or have different syntax for including parameters in SQL.

---

This logic also explain why named placeholders cannot be reused in non-emulated prepares.

The placeholder list is stored internally as a list of strings. Even if you try to use named placeholders twice with native prepares, the code cannot handle the binding. It will traverse the list and stop on the first match. For example, with SQL like this:

```
SELECT :one, :two, :one
```

The map will look like this: `[':one', ':two', ':one']`

If you then try to execute it, there will be only 2 params `execute([':one' => 1, 'two' => 2])`. They will be mapped to position 1 and 2 respectively. This means that position number 3 will never be mapped with any value. This should explain why using named placeholders with native PS is not possible.

---

<sup>*</sup> PDO actually remaps positional params back to named as well because different drivers bind params in different ways and it needs to be robust. See for example [Oracle - Named Binds and Positional Binds](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58234/bind_def.htm)